# Adding a header to a CSV file program using C#

Tags: c#, csv

```
 InitializeComponent();

 conDB = new csvfile();
 conDB.Path = "E:\\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs" + 
 DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

 fillCombo();
```

As beginner of programming and a very first time doing CRUD to a csv file in c#. I refer to this link:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27a98772-2dc6-4197-9f75-6cc119d4a88a/how-to-edit-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs that I've been located my source and useful to my program. But it was not satisfy to my specific satisfaction. I want to add header from it. Yes, I successfully added a header using this code.

```
   String newFileName = "E:\\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs" +
   DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

        string clientHeader = "\"EmployeeCode\"" + ",\"" + "Date" + "\",\""+
        "Time" + "\",\"" + "Type" + "\",\"" + "Remarks" + "\"" +
        Environment.NewLine;

        File.WriteAllText(newFileName, clientHeader);

        conDB.InsertEntrie(txtidno.Text, DatePicker.Text, TimePicker.Text, 
        cmbtype.Text, txtremarks.Text);
            //txtID.Text = Convert.ToString(conDB.Entries()-1);
            txtvalue = Convert.ToString(conDB.Entries() - 1);

        fillCombo();
        txtidno.Text = "";
        DatePicker.Text = "";
        TimePicker.Text = "";
        cmbtype.Text = "";
        txtremarks.Text = "";
```

But after successfully added my header like this:
"EmployeeCode","Date","Time","Type","Remarks"
The flow of codes are infected by this type of field in the header. Note! I change the format just like what my header form. The rest of my function that reading the line in csv file is affected by my header.It return to undesirable error. Hope that anyone can rescue me to my Island of error.

Comment: There's no such thing as CRUD when working with text files. You can't *search*, you can't *update*, you can't* delete. Only read the entire file, append lines *at the end*, or rewrite the entire file. If you want to add a line anywhere else, you'll have to copy the original text. In your case, read everything in memory and then write out the headers first, then the rest of the content

Comment: No. There is. I try the code in the link above. It works. but after I adding the header, the flow of passing values are broken and its hard for me to debug how.

Comment: no there isn't. What you call CRUD has nothing to do with the real meaning of the acronym. CRUD means working on individual records. Your code rewrites the entire file. You *can't* update a single line because (a) you can't even find the line offset unless all records have exactly the same byte length and (b) you'll overwrite other lines, for the same reason. You can't insert anything, because you'll have to *copy* the rest of the file out of the way. You can only *append* text at the end of the file

Comment: Come on, Just try it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute all that StreamWriter code with a more concise [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) and replace your string concatenations with an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings).
These changes will result in a more clean InsertEntry method

```
public bool InsertEntry(string idnumber, string date, string time, string type, string remarks)
{
    try
    {
        string line = $"\"{idnumber}\",\"{date}\",\"{time}\",\"{type}\",\"{remarks}\"{Environment.NewLine}";
        File.AppendAllText(data_path, line);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        string temp = ee.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, the button1 click should write the header just one time, not everytime it is clicked. To avoid this from happening you need to check if the file exists or not before writing the header.

```
String newFileName = @"E:\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs" + 
                     DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv");
if(!File.Exists(newFileName))
{
    string clientHeader = $"\"EmployeeCode\",\"Date\",\"Time\",\"Type\",\"Remarks\"{Environment.NewLine}";
    File.WriteAllText(newFileName, clientHeader);
}
```

Comment: Added a check to exclude writing the header if the file exists

Comment: File.WriteAllText(newFileName, clientHeader); = error said: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'E:\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs\20170608.csv'.'

Comment: Well this is pretty clear. There is no path like _E:\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs_ If the drive E exists we can add a _[Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)(@"E:\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs");_

Comment: Or if your intent is to have a file named like E:\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs20170608.csv then just remove the Path.Combine and uses your original code.

Comment: I mean _String newFileName = "E:\\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs" +
        DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";_ then check for file exists or not

Comment: To be honest. I am beginner in programming. Can you show me the codes?or better update your answer and may be easy of the other to use as references also.

Comment: Yeah..It works but the next I put other entry it is not adding to the next line.it is concatenating in the second line..                                             string line = $"\"{idnumber}\",\"{date}\",\"{time}\",\"{type}\",\"{remarks}\"";        how I will add "\n" .It is possible?

Comment: @Sam did you try the latest answer?

Comment: Thank you so much @Steve, I try your code and it is now appending to the next line but there is no header written. When I add my code in adding a header to the form load event the header is added but when adding more data it is overwritten or replacing always the data in 2nd line. So I delete the adding header code from form load event and by the next run of program it is now appending to the next line. And when I delete the directory of the csv file to start the program again for testing. The header is not written but appending data to the next line. It was so tricky code here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem credit with the help of Steve.
First of all I add this code to the form.

```
  InitializeComponent();
  conDB = new csvfile();
  conDB.Path = "E:\\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs" + 
  DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

  String newFileName = "E:\\BR_AttendanceDownloadLogs" + 
  DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

  if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
  {
    string clientHeader = "\"EmployeeCode\"" + ",\"" + "Date" + "\",\"" +
    "Time" + "\",\"" + "Type" + "\",\"" + "Remarks" + "\"" +
    Environment.NewLine;
    File.WriteAllText(newFileName, clientHeader);
  }
  fillCombo();
```

Then to my other class I add this function to add entry from the user input. Thanks to steve.

```
  public bool InsertEntrie(string idnumber, string date, string time, string 
  type, string remarks)
    {            
        CreateConfigFile();
        try
        {
           string line = $"\"{idnumber}\",\"{date}\",\"{time}\",\"
            {type}\",\"{remarks}\"{Environment.NewLine}";
            File.AppendAllText(data_path, line);                
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            string temp = ee.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then I have this code to my form in button click event.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
       conDB.InsertEntrie(txtidno.Text, DatePicker.Text, TimePicker.Text, 
       cmbtype.Text, txtremarks.Text);
       txtvalue = Convert.ToString(conDB.Entries() - 1);
    }
```