# Adding a header to multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv

Can anyone guide me on how to add a header to multiple csv files?

Optional: If anyone knows a method add add a header to pre-existing files in C# or can guide me to the relevant resources. That would be great.

```
import os
import os.path as path

## First create a function that will generate random files.
def create_random_csv_files(fault_classes, number_of_files_in_each_class):
    os.mkdir("./random_data/")  # Make a directory to save created files.
    for fault_class in fault_classes:
        for i in range(number_of_files_in_each_class):
            data = np.random.rand(1024,3)
            file_name = "./random_data/" + eval("fault_class") + "_" + "{0:03}".format(i+1) + ".csv" # This creates file_name
            np.savetxt(eval("file_name"), data, delimiter = ",", comments = "")
        print(str(eval("number_of_files_in_each_class")) + " " + eval("fault_class") + " files"  + " created.")
```

Comment: do not use eval ever!

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko ever? Eh, there are even places in the standard library that use `eval`. However, the overuse of it is definitely a red flag

Comment: @ShaR, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428125/1886644 for the way to add a header to a csv file in C#.

Comment: @C.Nivs very often this is not a good practice. For 10 years I used few times

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko agreed it's definitely not good practice, I've never used it in my years of developing. However, that's not to say it doesn't have its place

Comment: `np.savetxt` has a `header` parameter. Just add the header there.

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko can you please tell me why it's not the best of practices? I am a beginner when it comes to using python.

Comment: BTW, `eval("fault_class")` seems like a difficult way to write `fault_class` and makes the code harder to read.

Comment: @ShaR `eval`, and its cousin `exec`, will execute arbitrary code without checking if it's safe code. Most of the time, whenever you are using those functions (especially a lot), you can refactor to a more efficient and pythonic implementation

Comment: `eval` is fine when you have a dynamically created python expression but a massive security hole if any of the data used to construct the expression comes from an untrusted source. I have only rarely used `eval` and it was to fetch expressions in a database from a trusted source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import os.path as path

## First create a function that will generate random files.
def create_random_csv_files(fault_classes, number_of_files_in_each_class):
    os.mkdir("./random_data/")  # Make a directory to save created files.
    for fault_class in fault_classes:
        for i in range(number_of_files_in_each_class):
            data = np.random.rand(1024,3)
            file_name = "./random_data/" + eval("fault_class") + "_" + "{0:03}".format(i+1) + ".csv" # This creates file_name
            np.savetxt("file_name", data, delimiter = ",", header = "V1,V2,V3", comments = "")
        print(str("number_of_files_in_each_class") + " " + "fault_class" + " files"  + " created.")
```